# How to increase value by 1 in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which I have following details:

```
code
20190904NGH0001
20190904NGH0002
20190904NGH0006
20190904NGH0005
```

Now I want to get the max data from these data and have to increase value by +1.

So for example if `20190904NGH0006` then in next I need `20190904NGH0007`.

So I have written below stored procedure.

```
declare @Newcode varchar(100) , @LastCode varchar(MAX)
set @Newcode = 'NGH'
Select @LastCode = MAX(SUBSTRING(code, CHARINDEX(@Newcode, code)+LEN(@Newcode ), LEN(code))) from ticket where codelike '%'+@Newcode+'%'
select @LastCode as newvalue
```

Form above stored procedure i am getting below output :

```
newvalue
0006
```

So to increase I have tried:

```
Select @LastCode = MAX(SUBSTRING(ticketreference, CHARINDEX(@code, ticketreference)+LEN(@code), LEN(ticketreference)))+1  from ticket where ticketreference like '%'+@code+'%'
```

But I am getting only 7. I need 0007.

So finally I need to increase +1 in max value.

Example: if `0100` is the max than I need `0101`

Comment: The problem here is your trying to treat a string like a number. `'20190904NGH0006' + 1` = *Conversion error* and `'20190904NGH0006' + '1'` = `'20190904NGH00061'`. This looks more like you should be storing the values as different parts and then using a computed column. Are you trying to get that value for a `INSERT`? if so, have you thought about race conditions?

Comment: Also, in case you were aware (though I mentioned in a prior deleted comment), SQL Server 2008 is now completely unsupported. You should really be looking into upgrade paths as soon as you can.

Comment: It's easy to solve this problem with a SEQUENCE introduced in SQL Server 2012. Instead of trying to parse previous values, generate a new number and concatenate it with the rest of the string. You *really* need to upgrade

Comment: In any case the problem becomes a lot easier when you can calculate the sequence values you need in advance instead of trying to parse older values. If anything, trying to group over a calculated string will have to scan *the entire table*. There are a lot of ways you can create sequential numbers. If you stored the date and sequence in *separate* columns, you could get a new sequence number for a specific date with `select MAX(Seq)+1 from ticket where DateColum=cast(getdate() as date)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your stored procedure has gotten the last value as 0006, then you can use this to get the next Value:

```
Declare @LastValue varchar(4), @NewValue varchar(4)
select @LastValue = '0006'
select @NewValue = right ( ('0000' + ltrim(rtrim(str(convert(int,@LastValue)+1))) ),4)
select @NewValue
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try this below option-

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX)  = '20190904NGH0001'

SELECT  
SUBSTRING(@S,1,LEN(@S)-4) + 
REPLICATE(
    '0', 
    4 - LEN(CAST(CAST(RIGHT(@S,4) AS INT) + 1 AS VARCHAR))
) + 
CAST(
    CAST(RIGHT(@S,4) AS INT) + 1 AS varchar
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t+cnt as code from (
select substring(code,1,len(code)-1) as t,convert(varchar(50),max(substring(code,len(code),1) + 1)) cnt from YOURTABLE
group by substring(code,1,len(code)-1)
) abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. You can pass any Alphanumeric string having integer at the last of string. It will take the integer part from the last and increment it by `1` to make same formatted new string.

```
declare @ss varchar(15) = '20190904NGH0009'
; with cte as(
select Substring(@ss, 1, Len(@ss) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', reverse(@ss))+1) as suf,
Substring(@ss, Len(@ss) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', reverse(@ss))+2, len(@ss)) as pref 
)
select suf + 
REPLICATE('0', len(pref) - len(cast(pref as int)+1)) +     
cast( cast(pref as int)+1 as varchar(10)) 
from cte

--- cast(pref as int)+1 this is portion where we add 1. you may chnge 1 to any number as per your need
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This.Perfect Answer

```
declare @Newcode varchar(100) ,
@LastCode varchar(MAX)
set @Newcode = 'NGH'
Select @LastCode =max(REPLACE((STR
(SUBSTRING(code,(CHARINDEX(@Newcode, code)+LEN(@Newcode))
         ,LEN(code))+1,
       len(code)-(CHARINDEX(@Newcode, code)+LEN(@Newcode)-1) 
))
,' ',0))
from ticket where  code like '%'+@Newcode+'%'

select @LastCode as newvalue
```